# Database Replication

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I have tried to follow the steps outlined in
http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication
for Database Replication.
I have created the database exampledb, and create some tables and load them with values.

But when I execute 
USE exampledb;
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;

I do not get any output, it says 0 rows affected.
why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I find that 'Show Master Status' says very little about the replication status. Using 'Show Slave Status' on the Slave server is far more useful for showing current status of replication.  For example: is the replication caught up to the master, have there been any errors, does the transaction count match the master.